# TSQL Update Column based on other Column

Tags: sql

I've below table with data,

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Test](
        [Id1] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Id2] [int] NOT NULL,
        [id3] [int] NOT NULL,
        [D_OldValue] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [R_Value] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id1] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO


    USE [temporary_databases];
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Test]([Id1], [Id2], [id3], [D_OldValue], [R_Value])
SELECT 437, 163, 163, N'BW', N'Ford' UNION ALL
SELECT 493, 163, 163, N'BW', N'Stock' UNION ALL
SELECT 1224, 163, 163, N'BW', N'Wood' UNION ALL
SELECT 1225, 163, 163, N'BW', N'FRD' UNION ALL
SELECT 1232, 163, 163, N'BW', N'COW' UNION ALL
SELECT 1240, 163, 163, N'BW', N'FRD1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2160, 163, 163, N'BW', N'Log'
COMMIT;
RAISERROR (N'[dbo].[tbl_Test]: Insert Batch: 1.....Done!', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
GO
```

I've requirement in my excel as below

+------+-----+-----+------------+---------+------------+

```
| Id1  | Id2 | id3 | D_OldValue | R_Value | D_NewValue |

+------+-----+-----+------------+---------+------------+

|  437 | 163 | 163 | BW         | Ford    | BF         |

|  493 | 163 | 163 | BW         | Stock   | WS         |

| 1224 | 163 | 163 | BW         | Wood    | WS         |

| 1225 | 163 | 163 | BW         | FRD     | BF         |

| 1232 | 163 | 163 | BW         | COW     | WS         |

| 1240 | 163 | 163 | BW         | FRD1    | BF         |

| 2160 | 163 | 163 | BW         | Log     | WS         |

+------+-----+-----+------------+---------+------------+
```

> now I need to update D_OldValue column in (tbl_test) with D_NewValue
>   (Excel Table) I've tried with simple Update query like 
>       Update tbl_Test set D_OldValue = 'BF' where D_OldValue = 'BW'  But it updates all BW to BF Final output should be

```
+------+-----+-----+------------+---------+
| Id1  | Id2 | id3 | D_OldValue | R_Value |
+------+-----+-----+------------+---------+
|  437 | 163 | 163 | BF         | Ford    |
|  493 | 163 | 163 | WS         | Stock   |
| 1224 | 163 | 163 | WS         | Wood    |
| 1225 | 163 | 163 | BF         | FRD     |
| 1232 | 163 | 163 | WS         | COW     |
| 1240 | 163 | 163 | BF         | FRD1    |
| 2160 | 163 | 163 | WS         | Log     |
+------+-----+-----+------------+---------+

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the below query all the rows will be updated. If you want to update particular rows, add where condition

```
Update tbl_Test set D_OldValue = D_NewValue
```

Comment: Hi Vijay...you query works fine if D_NewValue column is present in the table. Actually in my requirement there is no such D_NewValue column, only D_OldValue column is available. I wrongly mentioned that in question. In requirement excel sheet we have both D_OldValue and D_NewValue, if this is the case how to write update query?

Comment: vijay..I've updated the question. Please look. I need to update tbl_Test based on the D_NewValue in the excel sheet table. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Then you need to write update query for each row using ID1(unique) (Update tbl_Test set D_OldValue = 'BF' where Id1  = 437) or If you have a large number of rows, then you have to upload you excel values into new table and try to update using the that